# Rose plant original

Tags: roses, suckers

[image]

Rose plant original stem or plant sucker stem, can I remove or keep it like same?

[image: stem of a rose plant]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suckers arise from below the graft or union - that might be at the top of the stem if its a standard rose (grafted onto a tall, straight stem) or more usually at the base of the stem, so check where the stems you're worried about are coming from. Move the soil aside if the point of origin is not visible and if its coming from below the graft (the knobbly bit) take it off. If its above, leave it, its a rose stem.